# Handle errors thrown by require() module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

having a bit of a snag in my code when trying to require() modules that don't exists.
The code loops through a directory and does a `var appname = require('path')` on each folder. This works for appropriately configured modules but throws: `Error: Cannot find module` when the loop hits a non-module.

I want to be able to handle this error gracefully, instead of letting it stop my entire process. So in short, how does one catch an error thrown by `require()`?

thanks!

Answer (score 71):

looks like a try/catch block does the trick on this e.g.

```
try {
 // a path we KNOW is totally bogus and not a module
 require('./apps/npm-debug.log/app.js')
}
catch (e) {
 console.log('oh no big error')
 console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: this works but seems odd, is there any other solutions?

Comment: I think because it's synchronous, error handling follows the regular js pattern here which generally sucks

Comment: A bit hacky but this works for me. 99.99% of the time the file will be present, performance is critical and I don't want to incur the overhead of requiring fs to check for the file before loading.

Answer (score 46):

> If the given path does not exist, require() will throw an Error with its code property set to 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules

So do a require in a try catch block and check for `error.code == 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'`

```
var m;
try {
    m = require(modulePath);
} catch (e) {
    if (e.code !== 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') {
        throw e;
    }
    m = backupModule;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Use a wrapper function:

```
function requireF(modulePath){ // force require
    try {
     return require(modulePath);
    }
    catch (e) {
     console.log('requireF(): The file "' + modulePath + '".js could not be loaded.');
     return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
requireF('./modules/non-existent-module');
```

Based on OP answer of course

Answer (score 3):

If the issue is with files that don't exist, what you should do is:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');
let requiredModule = null; // or a default object {}

let pathToModule = path.join(__dirname, /* path to module */, 'moduleName');
if (fs.existsSync(pathToModule)) {
  requiredModule = require(pathToModule);
}

// This is in case the module is in node_modules
pathToModule = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'moduleName');
if (fs.existsSync(pathToModule)) {
  requiredModule = require(pathToModule);
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect usage of fs.exists() (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) You probably meant fs.existsSync()

Comment: I agree with @TristanShelton, the idea here is to ensure all `require()` calls work as expected *before* the asynchronous side of the app starts working. Pretty sure this is one of the reasons that synchronous functions exist... However, the docs recommend `access()` over `exists()`, so perhaps [`accessSync()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_accesssync_path_mode) would be even more appropriate here.

Comment: Yes @TristanShelron, I agree, sorry for the mistake

Comment: Doesn't this have the race condition that the file can disapper inbetween testing that it exists and trying to require it?    That's the whole reason for trying and catching the error...