# Handling "Cannot find module" error when calling node.js fork

Tags: node.js, error-handling

How do I catch .fork() errors that call files that don't exist?

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var fk = cp.fork("missing-file.js");
```

spews out

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'path-to-here/missing-file.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

I've tried

```
try {
    var cp = require('child_process');
    var fk = cp.fork("missing-file.js");
} catch(err) {
    console.log("async error doesn't get caught here.");
}

fk.on('error', function(err) {
   console.log("this never gets called");
})

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log("this never gets called either");
});
```

but none of those catch the error.

[Joyent's documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_error) says an error event should be emitted when:

1. The process could not be spawned, or
2. The process could not be killed, or
3. Sending a message to the child process failed for whatever reason.

But this appears to happen prior to #1.

I looked at [Handle errors thrown by require() module in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197795/handle-errors-thrown-by-require-module-in-node-js) but the solution there doesn't work.

How do I catch this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no error here.  `node` started just fine, failed to find the file, and then exited.  None of these things will throw an error in the parent process.  However, the second step ("failed to find the file") caused the child process to emit some text on its `stdout`, which by default was inherited from the parent process.  That's the source of the text you're seeing (to suppress it, pass `fork` the `silent: true` option).

If you're trying to detect this error, you can put a handler on the `close` event.  That handler will be called with 2 arguments, but you only care about the 1st one: the exit code.  Node uses exit code 8 when it can't find the source file (although note that a script can also use exit code 8, so this isn't bullet-proof).  Note that exit code 0 conventionally means the process ended successfully.

So, if you want to act on the file not being found and suppress the error message from going to `stdout`, you can:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var fk = cp.fork("missing-file.js", {silent: true});
fk.on('close', function(code) {
  if(code == 8) {
    // Handle the missing file case here.
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution.  I confused myself by thinking that my child process wasn't running because my script isn't running--but node is the child process, and .fork() obscured that enough to fool me (.spawn() makes that obvious).  +1 for the {silence:true} tip!

Comment: How about if I want to also have access to the real error? I used 'error' event on child process in the parent but it never fires if the child js file does not exist

Comment: @Sam I mentioned this in my answer - cp.fork does not consider that an error, so there is no "real" error.  As far as it cares, the subprocess (node.js) started just fine, and then exited normally (albeit with a non-zero exit code).

Comment: @AaronDufour thanks. I was looking for a work around. If I use exec instead then I could have to such error too? by the way what the "silent" option does in your code when it cannot send its std info to the parent? thanks

Comment: @Sam I don't know of any other function that behaves similarly but triggers an error if the child process returns a non-zero exit code.  You could write this function yourself, though - just trigger the error handler if the `code` in the close event is non-zero.  The silent option causes the std info to just be ignored.

Comment: @AaronDufour thanks. Yes I could write but the problem is that different failures could have different codes. In my node it looks for many different internal problems like module not found it triggers code 1 rather than 8. So I could not really know what was the main reason of the error. But thanks anyhow

Comment: @Sam Yeah, exit codes are not a great error-signaling mechanism.  Unfortunately, there's nothing magic about `cp.fork` - it is under exactly the same constraints you just listed, which is why it doesn't do the thing you want.